# If pthread_cond_wait() requires locked mutex, doesn't it block the thread which changed condition?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

I need a two-threaded application. One thread prepare data, one process it. If there is no data to process, the second thread should sleep. Doing as tons of tutorials suggests:

```
pthread_mutex_t mtx;
pthread_cond_t cond;

char *shared_data = NULL;

char *process_data() {
    char *dt;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    if(!shared_data) pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);

    dt = strdup(shared_data);
    free(shared_data);
    shared_data = NULL;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

    return dt;
}

void create_data(char *dt) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

    shared_data = strdup(dt);

    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}
```

So, assuming the reader thread starts first.

1. The `shared_data` is currently NULL and there is nothing to read. So it locks the mutex and waits till `cond` is triggered.
2. The creator thread starts, it tries to lock the mutex, but it is already locked by the waiting reader...

Aren't we in a deadlock? What am I missing here?

Comment: `pthread_cond_wait()` unlocks mutex internally and locks back before return.

Comment: The behavior described by @dimich is well-documented.

Comment: You may want to use `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` to initialize the mutex though (unless you use `pthread_mutex_init` in code we don't see).

Comment: A _big_ fault with your code is  however using `if`. It should be `while(!shared_data) pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);` - see _spurious wakeups_.

Comment: @dimich Elaborate please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simplified world, this is what happens:

```c
pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

// the mutex is now locked so it's safe to access shared_data

if(!shared_data) // safe

    // now, unlock the mutex to let others lock it and when the condition
    // variable gets signalled, re-lock the mutex and return

    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);
```

So, there's no catch 22. The mutex is unlocked/relocked (sometimes multiple times) inside `pthread_cond_wait`. When `pthread_cond_wait` returns, it *will* be locked.

The most important part here that isn't quite `true` is that `pthread_cond_wait` may actually return even before the condition variable is signalled. This is called *spurious wakeups* and happens for implementation specific reasons. The only way to be sure that what you are waiting for has actually happend is to check that the shared resource has actually changed into the state you are waiting for.

Simply replace `if` with `while`.

```c
while(!shared_data)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);
```

Not replacing the `if` with `while` in your case *will* eventually bite you and you'll suddenly be using a `NULL` pointer in the following code.